# Bootstrap JavaScript not working in production environment (Rails 4)

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

Basics:
Rails 4
Ruby 2.0

We are stumped with why we can't get Bootstrap Javascript to work on Heroku when it works fine on our dev machine. We had it working with modals, but when we switched to tabs it stopped.

Application.js

```
//= require analytics
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree
```

production.rb

```
Entreuse::Application.configure do
config.cache_classes = true
config.eager_load = true
config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
config.serve_static_assets = false
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
config.assets.compile = false
config.assets.digest = true
config.assets.version = '1.0'
config.log_level = :info
```

development.rb

```
Entreuse::Application.configure do
config.cache_classes = false
config.eager_load = false
config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
config.active_support.deprecation = :log
config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load
config.assets.debug = true
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'fonts')
config.assets.precompile += %w( .svg .eot .woff .ttf)
```

gemfile

```
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem "haml", "~> 4.0.5"
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem "bootstrap-sass", "~> 3.1.1.0"
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 4.0.3.1'

group :doc do
gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

group :development, :test do
gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
gem 'pg'
gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

App on Heroku
http://www.entreuse.com/

Any insights would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Link provided isn't working at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We got this fixed!

The problem was with the analytics
//= require analytics

The error we were getting had to do with the fact that analytics.js.coffee was being included at the top before jQuery was included - it should be at the bottom after jQuery is included. So when it used the dollar sign method at the top of the js file, jQuery hadn't been defined yet.

This post was very helpful:
[Rails 4 turbolinks with Google Analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18945464/rails-4-turbolinks-with-google-analytics)