# Rails 4.1 analytics and site verification

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, google-analytics, ruby-on-rails-4.1

My site is in Rails 4.1.7 and is hosted in Ninefold.
I want to verify and add Google Analytics to it. 
I tried uploading html file in public folder, no go. 
I tried creating controller and route, didn't work.
I tried a couple of solutions that were supposed to do a workaround in turbolinks and added the analytics script to the footer.  Didn't work
Any ideas?
I must add that in the first two solutions, the html / action were accessible through the browser call but not through external links (when you try to verify, it gives you a link in webmasters tools), which has led me to believe it's a csrf situation, where rails blocks incoming connections from other websites.

**UPDATE:** I have [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25050377/2347665) solution live, analytics shows me some data but site verification still does not work.

**UPDATE 2:** Ok, i solved it.  The problem was that i had stated the domain as domain.com in Ninefold and forgot about it, and then i was trying to verify www.domain.com in Google.  Solved by adding the extra domain and verifying both of them.

Comment: You can try the **recommended** way, setting a `TXT` or `CNAME` record instead https://support.google.com/a/answer/183895

Comment: even if i do that, what about analytics? I don't think this can work with CNAME or TXT, right?

Comment: Without knowing exactly what solutions you've tried or seeing code showing a specific issue, I can't possibly help aside from point out that you're not the only one dealing with this issue and that there is a lot of information on google analytics working with turbolinks here on SO and elsewhere.

Comment: what part of the app do you want me to upload? i have this solution (http://stackoverflow.com/a/19527243/2347665) live right now and it still doesn't work.
Edit: i changed the link, i had another one in my clipboard and it was wrong.